# iAd sometimes not working

Tags: ios

I have put iAd in my app and for some reason when I run it in the simulator, it causes an error.

> ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unknown error" UserInfo=0x9258b10 {ADInternalErrorCode=0, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unknown error}

I have the frameworks and the header file done correctly, yet it does display advertisements and it sometimes gives this error

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because XCode can't find where your add is in your `storyboard` or `.xib` file. Also, your getting this error because you do not have the `didFailToReciveAdWithError` void. The code you should be using is below.

You don't need to do anything in your header file, just add the following code to your `.m` file:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
  [banner setAlpha:1];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *) banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:error{ 
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
  [banner setAlpha:0];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

again, you don't need ANYTHING in your header file. Next go into your `.xib` or `storyboard` file, and get rid of any `outlets`, or anything else hooked up to you're banner views. Next, right click on your `banner views` and drag the Outlet `delegate` to the `file's owner`

Comment: sorry if i sound noobish but Im not sure where the files owner part is at, i know everything else but that part

Comment: Are you using a `.xib` or a `storyboard`? @user2933653 if your using a `storyboard` it's actually going to be called your `ViewController` in you `storyboard` file, or whatever you named your `viewcontroller`.

Comment: have you figured it out?